# SQL issue- statement returning the same even though trying to sort the fielld using where - nested query - convert to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, join, subquery, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
select distinct(ab.id) 
from WidgetClicks ab
join  ManufacturerWidgets aa 
    on ab.ManufacturerWidgetId = aa.Id
join ManufacturerRetailers ad 
    on aa.ManufacturerId = ad.ManufacturerId
join Products ac 
    on ab.ProductId = ac.Id  
where ad.Enabled = 0 
    and ad.RetailerId = 189 
    and  aa.ManufacturerId = 46  
    and aa.CountryId = 72 
    and ac.Id = 6914 
    and ab.CreatedAt >= '2011-10-31 00:00:00.000' 
    and ab.CreatedAt <= '2012-03-31 00:00:00.000'
```

With enabled = 1 and the retailerId I get exactly the same results even though I shouldn't - the results should be a lot fewer.

I'm sure its something straightforward but its driving me mad! any help appreciated

EDIT:

What i actually need to do is basically write 3 statments to get the results - again not certain how to do this but this is what the statment needs to do (in plain english):

1. From the affiliateretailer table select * where manufacturerid = 46 and enabled = true
2. Select * from manufacturerRetailer where the retailers are the ones remaining in the above selection where manufacturerid = 46
3. Select * from widgetClicks  join on retialer d where productid = abc and wc.CreatedAt >= '2011-10-31 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt <= '2012-03-31 00:00:00.000'

Edit **

Right i've got the Sql query that i want...

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM WidgetClicks 
    WHERE CreatedAt >= '2011-10-31 00:00:00.000' 
    and CreatedAt <= '2012-03-31 00:00:00.000' 
    and ProductId = 6914 
    AND RetailerId in (
                        SELECT RetailerId 
                        FROM AffiliateUpdateFiles auf
                        WHERE auf.Enabled = 1 AND auf.ManufacturerId = 46 and RetailerId <> 189
                        )
    AND ManufacturerWidgetId in (
                                select id 
                                from ManufacturerWidgets 
                                where  ManufacturerId = 46 and CountryId = 72
                                )
```

Here's the thing thoug - I actually need it in Linq - if anyone can convert it for me it woudl be appreciated... i will be having a go!

Comment: Shouldn't it return more results if you take out `Enabled` and `RetailerID`?

Comment: sorry thats what i mean - i get more results with enabled = 1 and the retailer id in when i would expect to get less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for converting the above to Linq:

```
public int GetWidgetClicksForManufacturerCategoryModel(int manufacturerId, int countryId, int categoryId, int productId, DateTime myStartDate, DateTime myEndDate)
        {
            var widgetInCountry = (from mw in _er.ManufacturerWidgets
                                                where mw.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId && mw.CountryId == countryId
                                                select mw.Id).ToList();

            var enabledWidgets = (from auf in _er.AffiliateUpdateFiles
                        where auf.Enabled && auf.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId 
                        select auf.RetailerId).ToList();



            var widgetClicks = (from wc in _er.WidgetClicks
                          where wc.CreatedAt.CompareTo(myStartDate) >= 0 && wc.CreatedAt.CompareTo(myEndDate) <= 0 
                          && wc.ProductId == productId 
                          && enabledWidgets.Contains(wc.RetailerId) 
                          && widgetInCountry.Contains(wc.ManufacturerWidgetId)
                                               select wc.Id);

            return widgetClicks.Count();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using LEFT OUTER JOINs instead. This will return results from WidgetClicks even if there are no corresponding rows in your joined tables.

If you find that you get the rows you expect after changing your joins to LEFT OUTER JOINs, then examine the data in the joined tables - they don't contain the rows you expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure of your joins, if removing the "ad" table filters from the WHERE clause have no effect, it would indicate that the ab-to-aa join or the ab-to-ac join is filtering things out due to those WHERE clauses.

```
ab -- aa -- ad
|
ac
```

So try leaving the ad filters in the WHERE clause, but removing the rest and then adding them back one-by-one to see which WHERE filter is causing fewer results than you expect.  Once you see where things are getting filtered out, you can then determine what you need to change--and potentially restructure.  You may want to use some OUTER joins at that point or create joins to aliases tables, for example: X JOIN (Y OUTER JOIN Z WHERE ...) AS Q ON X.id = Q.id WHERE ...